# Java interrupting thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have code like below. I have the following problem: I must stop `Thread t`, but inside is a method which suspends the thread in one place for long time. So when I'm  trying to stop it, it stops after that method is executed. Anyone know how to terminate this thread or stop it in any other way while executing the method inside the thread?

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame implements Runnable{       
    @Override
    public void run() {   
        OtherClass oc = new OtherClass();
        Runnable r = oc;
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();

        addButton(buttonPanel, "Stop it", new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("stopping");
                t.stop();                      
                setVisible(false);                
            }
        }); 
    }
}    

public void addButton(Container c, String title, ActionListener listener) {
    JButton button = new JButton(title);
    c.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Where is the thread waiting? Also, never use `Thread.stop()`.

Comment: I'm not a Swing expert, but `extends JFrame implements Runnable` sounds like a recipe for trouble.    Why `implements Runnable`?  Where is that `run()` method called from?

Comment: See [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: `run` method is called from other class. It's not complete listing.

Comment: You should use `Thread.interrupt()`, as mentioned.  If you're doing a lot of looping inside that thread, periodically call `Thread.interrupted()` to check if a stop has been requested.

Comment: @markspace i cant do this, becouse inside thread i have method call which pause it for long time (making calculations)

Comment: This method would definitely have a loop, use this loop to check for `Thread.interrupted()` or use a volatile boolean variable which is set on click of stop button.

Comment: I don't know what is inside, because its compiled code.